# Set font style to Courier New and font size of 10pt in framed

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I would like to change the font from Times New Roman to Courier New in the `framed` environment and it should have a font size of 10pt.

Here my current coding:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
define("USE_PCONNECT", false);
####### LOCAL CONFIGARATION  #######
define("SERVER","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASSWORD","");
define("DB","learning");
\end{lstlisting}
```

In my document file:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
numberstyle=\small, 
numbersep=10pt, 
frame = single, 
language=PHP
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: When you have new information, please edit your original question, don't post the information in a comment. Also, as stated in my initial comment, please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the hints reg. how to ask questions, here a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle  = \fontfamily{pcr}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont ,
  numberstyle = \small , 
  numbersep   = 10pt   , 
  frame       = single , 
  language    = PHP
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
define("USE_PCONNECT", false);
####### LOCAL CONFIGARATION  #######
define("SERVER","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASSWORD","");
define("DB","learning");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```